# Download CSV file from FTP server to save locally and process for Uploading

Tags: php, file, download

I need to write a PHP script that downloads a file (master.csv) from an ftp server (ftp.example.com) and prepares it for processing and uploading. I've tried this a number of times but my code is no good, I'm new to PHP. How would I go about doing this?

```
<?php
///vars
$local_file = 'xmitpart2.csv';
$server_file = 'master.csv';
$ftp_server="ftp.example.com";
$ftp_user="username";
$ftp_pass="paswd";

//connect to server
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login to ftp
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);

//download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)) 
{
    echo "Holy Crap Finally!\n";
}
else 
{
    echo "Of Course.\n";
    //WRONGO DIE DIE DIE
    die;
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use   [ftp_get();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php)

It allows you to get a file from an FTP server and save it locally.

Once you have it saved locally you can do what ever you want to "prepare it" as you say.